# Python: Program opens incorrect filepath in explorer?

Tags: python, list, filepath, explorer, os.system

Im trying to have my program open a filepath entered by the user. This entry is saved in my `data [0]` list which I then call on using the `os.system` function. Instead of opening the saved filepath, explorer opens and takes me to My Documents. **1. Why does this happen?**    **2. How do I change this to have explorer open to the saved user data?**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import pickle
import os


data = []

class MyPath(tk.Frame):


def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.pack()
    MyPath.make_widgets(self)

def make_widgets(self):
    self.parent.title("MyPath")

    #self.textbox = Text(root)
    #self.textbox.pack()

    # create a prompt, an input box, an output label,
    # and a button to do the computation
    self.prompt = tk.Label(self, text="Enter your Filepath:", anchor="w")
    self.textbox = tk.Text(self)
    self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
    self.open = tk.Button(self, text="Open", command = self.open)
    self.view = tk.Button(self, text="View", command = self.view)
    self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Save", command = self.save)
    self.output = tk.Label(self, text="")
    self.clear_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear text", command=self.clear_text)

    # lay the widgets out on the screen. 
    self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
    self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
    self.textbox.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    self.view.pack(side="bottom")
    self.submit.pack(side="bottom")
    self.clear_button.pack(side="bottom")
    self.open.pack(side="top")


def clear_text(self):
    self.entry.delete(0, 'end')
    self.textbox.delete(1.0, 'end')


def save(self):
    # get the value from the input widget

    try:
        a = self.entry.get()
        result = data.append(self.entry.get())

    except ValueError:
        result = "Please enter filepaths only"

    #saves list to pickle file
    #pickle.dump(data, open("save.p", "wb"))

    # set the output widget to have our result
    self.output.configure(text=result)
    print (data)

def view(self):
    pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
    self.textbox.insert("1.0", str(pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))))
    print pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))

def open(self):
    #src = "/Users/matt/Documents/Python/MyApp.py"
    dst = data
    #path = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
    os.system('Explorer "data[0]"')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MyPath(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: When calling instance methods, do `self.method()` instead of `Class.method(self)`. The latter form is commonly used for static methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.system('Explorer "%s"' % data[0])
```

Cause your string in the end looks like 'Explorer data[0]' and when explorer cannot find the path data[0] it reverts to default location for User - My Documents